# How to correctly apply a function to each row on a fast (parallel) way

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple rows belonging to one observation. So the information (costs) of an observation is located in multiple rows, where the costs of each cost category for that observation is located in a single row. In total, there are 80 different kind of cost categories, both variable and fixed costs. Not every observation has expenses on all cost categories.

I want to have all costs for each observation in one row.

I created a (new) dataframe with all the (unique) observations and I created the columns for each cost category, split in in fixed and variable costs.

Now I want to fill in the new dataframe efficiently with all the information from the original dataframe. For doing this, I created a function (for each row) that subsets the observation and all their belonging rows from the original dataset. This function returns one row. However, this function does not work for me in apply. This function is working really slow in a for loop, so this is not an option

```
#Three different fictional cost categories
costcats <- c("CAT1","CAT2","CAT3")

# A loop to create the new columns and fill with zero (for now) 
for(j in 1:length(costcats)){
  ALL_ONE_ROW[,paste("FIX",costcats[j],sep="")] <- 0
  ALL_ONE_ROW[,paste("VAR_",costcats[j],sep="")] <- 0
}
# PK is the unique identifier of an observation

# Function to subset multiple rows from original dataset and return one 
row
cost_fast <- function(row){
  d <- LARGE_COST %>% filter(PK==row["PK"])   #subset from the original

  for(i in 1:nrow(d)){    #Loop over the rows of the observation and fill 
the belonging column
    row[,paste("FIXED",d[i,"COSTCAT"],sep="_")] <- d[i,"FIXCOST"]
    row[,paste("VAR",d[i,"COSTCAT"],sep="_")] <- d[i,"VARCOST"]
  }
   return(row)   
}

#Apply the function to each row
ALL_ONE_ROW <- apply(ALL_ONE_ROW,1,cost_fast)
```

This code does work in a for loop, but is terribly slow. Therefore, I 
want to run this code as efficient as possible, because the datasets are 
quite large.

Example:

```
head(LARGE_COST)
                PK  COSTCAT FIXCST VARCOST
1 BI-73-01/04/2018     23Q -48.48  -48.48
2 BI-73-01/04/2018     41G 130.92       0
3 BI-73-01/04/2018     23Q 235.78  235.78
4 BI-73-01/04/2018     41G 173.48       0
5 BI-73-01/04/2018     22Q   0.19    0.19
6 BI-73-01/04/2018     23Q  40.35   40.35
```

I want to have:

```
PK               FIX_23Q VAR_23Q FIX_41G VAR_41G   .....
BI-73-01/04/2018   -48.48 -48.48  130.92       0   .....
```

Comment: You need to use the `[` subsetter, not `$` when working inside the function passed on to apply. Can you make your question reproducible? I also notice that `for (i in nrow(d))` should probably be `for (i in 1:nrow(d))`.

Comment: (1) Without seeing any data this is speculation, but ... using `apply` on a frame works only as long as your frame is all `numeric`. If anything is `character` then everything will be coerced to strings, defeating your function. (2) You only use it (`dplyr`) once, but in SO questions please be explicit about non-base R packages. (3) It would help to see a representative, unambiguous sample of your data, perhaps with `dput(head(ALL_ONE_ROW))`.

Comment: Laurens, it might not be necessary (or advisable) to have all of your costs in one row (especially because you would have to brutalize your variable names to have them all fit without duplicates). Using `tidyverse`, it is preferable (and easier!) to have your data as you have displayed it in your Example at the bottom of your post. What kinds of summaries/functions/analyses are you performing?

Comment: I'm not sure how useful the `multidplyr` package would be for this and how huge your dataset is, but there might be pretty accessible ways to parallelize this if need be. Also, if your data are really huge, you could probably split it up yourself to do this in several to many parallel pieces... from the looks of your data, maybe break up each month? I really like `furrr::future_map_dfr` which might let you use `tidyr` functions on sections of the data in parallel, and recombine into a single df.